# Bad argument in LDA constructor call in face recognition using LDA with SIFT

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, sift, lda

I am trying to implement face recognition using LDA with SIFT. I have an existing code of PCA with SIFT that uses SIFT to determine the keypoints and extract the descriptors and PCA to project those descriptors in the PCA sub-space. I am trying to achieve a similar functionality using LDA with SIFT.

I am trying to create an LDA object that will in turn call its member function 'project' but I get the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (The number of samples must equal the number of labels. Given 0 labels, 45 samples. ) in lda, file /home/shaurya/opencv-2.4.9/modules/contrib/src/lda.cpp, line 1015
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/mypath/opencv-2.4.9/modules/contrib/src/lda.cpp:1015: error: (-5) The number of samples must equal the number of labels. Given 0 labels, 45 samples.  in function lda Aborted (core dumped)
```

The following is the PCA with SIFT code that I have executed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        cout << "Usage: ./output <training database path> <test image>" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Reading training images paths
    vector<string> namesTrainingImages;
    vector<string>::iterator stringIt;

    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    if ((dir = opendir (argv[1])) != NULL) 
    {   
        while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) 
        {
            if((strcmp(ent -> d_name, ".") == 0) || (strcmp(ent -> d_name, "..") == 0))
            {
                continue;
            }
            string tempName(string(argv[1]) + string(ent -> d_name));
            namesTrainingImages.push_back(tempName);
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);

    vector<Mat> trainingImages;
    vector<Mat>::iterator imageIt;

    // Reading training images
    for(stringIt = namesTrainingImages.begin(); stringIt != namesTrainingImages.end(); ++stringIt)
    {
        Mat tempImage;
        tempImage = imread(*stringIt, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
        waitKey(5000);
        if(!tempImage.data )                              
        {
            cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            trainingImages.push_back(tempImage);
        }
    }

    vector< vector<KeyPoint> > keypoints;
    vector<Mat> descriptor;
    vector<Mat>::iterator descriptorIt;
    SIFT sift;

    double percentage = 0.95;

    for(imageIt = trainingImages.begin(); imageIt != trainingImages.end(); ++imageIt)
    {
        vector<KeyPoint> tempKeypoints;
        Mat tempDescriptor1, tempDescriptor2, tempDescriptor3;

        // Generating keypoints and descriptors from training images
        sift.operator()(*imageIt, *imageIt, tempKeypoints, tempDescriptor1, false);
        keypoints.push_back(tempKeypoints);

        // Using PCA to project and then backProject the descriptors of training images
        PCA pca(tempDescriptor1, Mat(), CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW, percentage);
        pca.PCA::project(tempDescriptor1, tempDescriptor2);
        tempDescriptor3 = pca.PCA::backProject(tempDescriptor2);
        descriptor.push_back(tempDescriptor3);      
    }


    // Reading the test image
    Mat testImage;
    testImage = imread(argv[2], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    waitKey(5000);
    if(!testImage.data)
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    vector<KeyPoint> testKeypoints;
    Mat testDescriptor, testDescriptor1, testDescriptor2;

    // Generating teh keypoints and the descriptor of the test image
    sift.operator()(testImage, testImage, testKeypoints, testDescriptor1, false);

    // Using PCA to project and then backProject the descriptor of the test image
    PCA pca(testDescriptor1, Mat(), CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW, percentage);
    pca.PCA::project(testDescriptor1, testDescriptor2);
    testDescriptor = pca.PCA::backProject(testDescriptor2);

    // Flann based matching to determine the best matching training image
    FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
    vector<DMatch> matches;
    vector<DMatch> good_matches;    
    int goodMatchesCtr = -1, tempCtr = -1, ctr = -1;

    for(descriptorIt = descriptor.begin(); descriptorIt != descriptor.end(); ++descriptorIt)
    {
        ++tempCtr;
        vector<DMatch> tempMatches;
        vector<DMatch> temp_good_matches;
        int tempGoodMatchesCtr = 0;
        double min_dist = 100;

        matcher.match(testDescriptor, *descriptorIt, tempMatches);

        for(int i = 0; i < testDescriptor.rows && i < (*descriptorIt).rows; ++i)
        {
            double dist = tempMatches[i].distance;
            if(dist < min_dist)
            {
                min_dist = dist;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < testDescriptor.rows && i < (*descriptorIt).rows; ++i)
        {

            if(tempMatches[i].distance <= max(2 * min_dist, 0.02))
            {
                temp_good_matches.push_back(tempMatches[i]);
                ++tempGoodMatchesCtr;
            }
        }

        if(tempGoodMatchesCtr > goodMatchesCtr)
        {
            goodMatchesCtr = tempGoodMatchesCtr;
            matches = tempMatches;
            good_matches = temp_good_matches;
            ctr = tempCtr;
        }
    }

    // Displaying the test image alongside the best matching training image
    Mat img_matches;

    drawMatches(testImage, testKeypoints, trainingImages[ctr], keypoints[ctr], good_matches, img_matches, Scalar ::all(-1), Scalar ::all(-1), vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);
    for( int i = 0; i < (int)good_matches.size(); ++i )
    { 
        printf( "-- Good Match [%d] Keypoint 1: %d  -- Keypoint 2: %d  \n", i, good_matches[i].queryIdx, good_matches[i].trainIdx ); 
    }
    imshow("Good Matches", img_matches);
    waitKey(0);

    cout << "Executed!" << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The following is the LDA with SIFT code that I am trying to execute:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        cout << "Usage: ./output <training database path> <test image>" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Reading training images paths
    vector<string> namesTrainingImages;
    vector<string>::iterator stringIt;

    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    if ((dir = opendir (argv[1])) != NULL) 
    {   
        while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) 
        {
            if((strcmp(ent -> d_name, ".") == 0) || (strcmp(ent -> d_name, "..") == 0))
            {
                continue;
            }
            string tempName(string(argv[1]) + string(ent -> d_name));
            namesTrainingImages.push_back(tempName);
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);

    vector<Mat> trainingImages;
    vector<Mat>::iterator imageIt;

    // Reading training images
    for(stringIt = namesTrainingImages.begin(); stringIt != namesTrainingImages.end(); ++stringIt)
    {
        Mat tempImage;
        tempImage = imread(*stringIt, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
        waitKey(5000);
        if(!tempImage.data )                              
        {
            cout <<  "Could not open or find a training image" << std::endl ;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            trainingImages.push_back(tempImage);
        }
    }

    vector< vector<KeyPoint> > keypoints;
    vector<Mat> descriptor;
    vector<Mat>::iterator descriptorIt;
    SIFT sift;

    for(imageIt = trainingImages.begin(); imageIt != trainingImages.end(); ++imageIt)
    {
        vector<KeyPoint> tempKeypoints;
        Mat tempDescriptor;

        // Generating keypoints and descriptors from training images
        sift.operator()(*imageIt, *imageIt, tempKeypoints, tempDescriptor, false);
        keypoints.push_back(tempKeypoints);

        // Trying to use LDA to project the descriptors of training images
        LDA lda(tempDescriptor, Mat());
        lda.LDA::project(tempDescriptor);
        descriptor.push_back(tempDescriptor);       
    }

    // Reading the test image
    Mat testImage;
    testImage = imread(argv[2], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    waitKey(5000);
    if(!testImage.data)
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    vector<KeyPoint> testKeypoints;
    Mat testDescriptor;

    // Generating the keypoints and the descriptor of the test image
    sift.operator()(testImage, testImage, testKeypoints, testDescriptor, false);

    // Trying to use LDA to project the descriptor of the test image
    LDA lda(testDescriptor, Mat());
    lda.LDA::project(testDescriptor);

    // Flann based matching to determine the best matching training image
    FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
    vector<DMatch> matches;
    vector<DMatch> good_matches;    
    int goodMatchesCtr = -1, tempCtr = -1, ctr = -1;

    for(descriptorIt = descriptor.begin(); descriptorIt != descriptor.end(); ++descriptorIt)
    {
        ++tempCtr;
        vector<DMatch> tempMatches;
        vector<DMatch> temp_good_matches;
        int tempGoodMatchesCtr = 0;
        double min_dist = 100;

        matcher.match(testDescriptor, *descriptorIt, tempMatches);

        for(int i = 0; i < testDescriptor.rows && i < (*descriptorIt).rows; ++i)
        {
            double dist = tempMatches[i].distance;
            if(dist < min_dist)
            {
                min_dist = dist;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < testDescriptor.rows && i < (*descriptorIt).rows; ++i)
        {

            if(tempMatches[i].distance <= max(2 * min_dist, 0.02))
            {
                temp_good_matches.push_back(tempMatches[i]);
                ++tempGoodMatchesCtr;
            }
        }

        if(tempGoodMatchesCtr > goodMatchesCtr)
        {
            goodMatchesCtr = tempGoodMatchesCtr;
            matches = tempMatches;
            good_matches = temp_good_matches;
            ctr = tempCtr;
        }
    }

    // Displaying the test image alogside the best matching training image
    Mat img_matches;

    drawMatches(testImage, testKeypoints, trainingImages[ctr], keypoints[ctr], good_matches, img_matches, Scalar ::all(-1), Scalar ::all(-1), vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);
    for( int i = 0; i < (int)good_matches.size(); ++i )
    { 
        printf( "-- Good Match [%d] Keypoint 1: %d  -- Keypoint 2: %d  \n", i, good_matches[i].queryIdx, good_matches[i].trainIdx ); 
    }
    imshow("Good Matches", img_matches);
    waitKey(0);

    cout << "Executed!" << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

I write these programs on the gedit text editor and execute these programs on Ubuntu 12.04 with OpenCV 2.4.9.

**EDIT**: Basically I want a way to convert the below given lines of SIFT-PCA code into SIFT-LDA

```
    PCA pca(testDescriptor1, Mat(), CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW, percentage);
    pca.PCA::project(testDescriptor1, testDescriptor2);
    testDescriptor = pca.PCA::backProject(testDescriptor2);
```

I tried to substitue the PCA constructor by the LDA constuctor in the following way:

```
    LDA lda(testDescriptor, Mat());
    lda.LDA::project(testDescriptor);
```

But I got the above mentioned error. My guess is that I am passing incorrect arguments to the LDA constructor. I have already gone through the documentation of LDA class given [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d59/classcv_1_1LDA.html), but had no luck in finding my mistake.

Any help regarding the above problem will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: lda is a supervised algo, you have to give it class labels (not an empty Mat()) . also, what is the purpose of it all ? applying pca or lda on the descriptors of a *single* image looks pretty weird to me.

Comment: I'm not sure if I correctly understand what class labels are. I have tried creating a vector of int, resized it to the size of the number of rows of the testImage, initialised the values to 0 and passed that as an argument, but it still doesn't work. Is it possible that you could give me a small example? Also, I am trying to apply LDA to 2 images and then match them using Flann. This is just a sample code that I am trying to implement to see how LDA works. And thank you very much for taking the time to reply to this question.

Comment: http://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/LDA/LDA.html